# How do I leave the Knife & Candle?

Tags: fallen-london

In Fallen London, how can I leave, possibly non-permanently, the Knife & Candle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have your Iron Knife Token, you can go to the Gamekeeper's Cottage on Watchmaker's Hill. Enter the Cottage and there should be an option to withdraw from the game. Note that this will remove all Iron Knife Tokens and you must reacquire one if you wish to rejoin the Game.

Comment: It was a bit hidden, but it worked!